# Mail encoding issue

Tags: mail.app, email, encoding

I have a problem with Mail. My name is Oğuz and there is a Turkish character in my name. I set up a 'live' email address in Mail. When I send an email from a web browser my name appears as "Oğuz", but when I send one from Mail my name appears as "O?uz". Also, other Turkish characters in my last name do not appear correctly. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.

1-) Create a new contact using name which you want to use as e-mail sender name.
2-) Add email account that contact.